# Using ng-if with multiple table rows in angular

Tags: angularjs

Right now I have the following html:

```
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Default</th>
    <th ng-if="c">A</th>
    <th ng-if="c">B</th>
    <th ng-if="c">C</th>
    <th ng-if="c">D</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
</body>
```

If $scope.c exists in my defaultCtrl, I want A, B, C, D to appear as table headers.

How can I group ng-if instead of repeating it 4 times?

When I try to put the four  elements in a div or span, I'm getting an error message saying that I'm invoking voodoo mode.

Comment: Do you really get an error that says voodoo mode? :) you might include the error message in your question...

Comment: You cannot group th's inside a span or div, which is invalid html. It must appear only within tr..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can definitely do it like this

```
<th ng-if="c" ng-repeat="x in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']">{{x}}</th>
```